# JMeter: Server Agent is getting stopped as soon as I am running the Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, perfmon

I am working on JMeter (version 5.2.1) and my requirement is to monitor the server health. Now for that I am using Perfmon plugins (jpgc-perfmon-2.1) and listener to catch the desired output. Also I have downloaded Server Agent (Server Agent-2.2.1 and Server Agent-2.2.3). I am hosting the script and running the server agent on the same machine.
Now for capturing the CPU utilization or Memory utilization first I am starting the server Agent and then I am running my JMeter script. But as I am clicking on the start button, the server agent is getting stopped automatically. Also I have tried communication between my local machine and server agent using telnet and its responding properly.

The Error Message I am getting in the JMeter console is:

```
Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:138) ~[?:?]
    at kg.apc.perfmon.client.StreamTransport.writeln(StreamTransport.java:50) ~[perfmon-2.2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.perfmon.client.AbstractTransport.disconnect(AbstractTransport.java:63) [perfmon-2.2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.NewAgentConnector.disconnect(NewAgentConnector.java:36) [jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.shutdownConnectors(PerfMonCollector.java:281) [jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.testEnded(PerfMonCollector.java:149) [jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.testEnded(ResultCollector.java:346) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:218) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:492) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) [?:?]
```

Can anyone help to solve this problem of automatically stopping the server agent.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue,Download the sigar-amd64-winnt.dll and put it under lib folder of your serverAgent. It is advisable to take a backup.

sigar-amd64-winnt.dll : https://github.com/cnstar9988/sigar/raw/master/sigar-amd64-winnt.dll.